# After updating virtualbox I now can't map to my drive

Tags: samba

I recently update Virtualbox to 4.3.18 which seems to have caused an issue connecting to Samba.

I can run my VM ok, and can view the site in browser. I can also ping my VM ip from cmd.

The only thing I am unable to do is map the drive either in windows or at the command line using net use.

From the command line I get

"System error 58 has occurred.

The specified server cannot perform the requested operation."

I have tried the following steps

GPedit.msc
Windows Settings. Expand “Local Policies” and select “Security Options”
Alternate : Type secpol.msc to get editor up then
Locate “Network Security: LAN Manager Authentication Level” in the list and double-click it.
Change the setting from “Send NTMLv2 response only” to “Send LM & NTLM – use NTLMv2 session if negotiated”

As well as making a couple of registry changes that I found on another post. But I am still unable to map the drive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar situation at my end and worked after changing the group policy settings. To change Security Settings | Local Policies | Security Options | Microsoft network client: Digitally sign communications (always) to disabled. You have to reboot the machine for the changes to take effect.

Hope this helps..